# Reading specific column of data from text file and write to another text file tcl

Tags: tcl

By using Tcl. For example, I have the data

```
hello;world;123
test;code;456
```

I just want to get the value of the first column and write it into another text file. Output will be like this.

```
hello
test
```

Comment: @HappyCoder wanna get the specific column of data for comparison =)

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. You are expected to have made some attempt to solve the problem yourself before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have just to read from input file:

```
set pfi [open "file_name" "r"]
set cnt [gets $pfi row]
```

then filter the first word:

```
set word [lindex [split $row ";"] 0]
```

then write in the output file

```
set pfo [open "file_out_name" "w"]
puts $pfo $word
```

You can use cnt to know if the end of file is coming (when cnt < 0 the file is ended) so you can iterate on all row of file. Of course, at the end, it's necessary to close the files:

```
close $pfi
close $pfo
```

So, combining all steps:

```
set pfi [open "file_in_name" "r"]
set pfo [open "file_out_name" "w"]
while {1 == 1} {
    set cnt [gets $pfi row]
    if {$cnt < 0} {break}
    set word [lindex [split $row ";"] 0]
    puts $pfo $word
}
close $pfi
close $pfo
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah well...

There are a few ways to do this. If you're on a unix-like platform, the `cut` command is the right way, from inside Tcl or a shell script. Tcl can do it too, of course, though not as conveniently (it's hard for a script to compete with a utility).

The easiest solutions leverage `fileutil`, one of the world's most underrated packages:

```
package require fileutil
namespace import ::fileutil::*
```

One command, `foreachLine`, lets us do something for each line in a file (`data.old`):

```
foreachLine line data.old {appendToFile data.new [lindex [split $line \;] 0]\n}
```

What we do here is append the sought-for word on each line to another file (`data.new`).

We can also edit a file in-place, with the help of a command that splits the file's contents in lines, truncates each line to the first substring up to a semicolon, and then rejoins the lines:

```
proc cmd data {
    join [lmap line [split [string trim $data] \n] {
        lindex [split $line \;] 0
    }] \n
}
```

And then we do it (note that this replaces the original contents):

```
updateInPlace data.old cmd
```

This is a bit more involved but practical for manipulations that aren't strictly line-for-line.

Another couple of packages are helpful with character-separated data: `csv` to import the data set, and `struct::matrix` to manipulate the data.

```
package require csv
package require struct::matrix

::struct::matrix m
```

Import the data into the matrix `m` (because of how the package is defined, we need to deal with channels here):

```
set old [open data.old]
::csv::read2matrix $old m \; auto
chan close $old
```

Get the first column from the matrix:

```
set data [m get column 0]
```

Write the truncated data to the file:

```
writeFile data.new [join $data \n]
```

It is of course also possible to do this in a low-level, core-Tcl way. This solution is similar to Andrea Tosoni's, but a little more idiomatic.

```
set old [open data.old]
set new [open data.new w]
while {[chan gets $old line] >= 0} {
    chan puts $new [lindex [split $line \;] 0]
}
chan close $old
chan close $new
```

Documentation: [chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm), [csv](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.html) package, [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html) package, [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [lmap](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570) replacement, [namespace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [struct::matrix](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/struct/matrix.html) package, [while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm)